# Expectation of Brownian motion given a future value: $E(W_s | W_t), s < t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, brownian-motion

Consider a Brownian motion / Wiener process $W_t$. I'm interested in calculating $E(W_s | W_t)$ when $s < t$.

I've considered decomposing $W_s = W_t - (W_t - W_s)$, but then I'm still stuck with $E(W_s | W_t) = W_t - E(W_t - W_s | W_t)$.

My guess is that the answer will be $\frac{s}{t} W_t$. Since we know that $W_0 = 0$, and given $W_t$, the process must "make its way" from $0$ to $W_t$, and I feel that it would only make sense for that to happen linearly in time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $W_s$ and $W_t$ are jointly normal, we can decompose $W_s$ as $W_s = aW_t + U $, where $U \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a normally distributed random variable independent of $W_t$, and $a, \mu, \sigma^2$ are constants to be determined (in terms of $s$ and $t$).

Comment: Your conjecture is correct, by the way.